# Bizarre nexus of occurrences: loss of reputation + review privileges

Tags: support, reputation, review-suspension

I am wondering what is going on.  Suddenly I find myself banned from reviewing and 6 of my old questions now give me -2 scores.

Review ban:

- **Q1**: 3 years, 9 months ago, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32216804, no reason given, actually it does not show any rejection, I guess someone did not like the extra spaces for code formatting.
- **Q2**: 4 years ago, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32382246, reason given "*highlighting/bolding so many words and phrases makes it harder to read, not easier*.".  Ok why not...

-2 questions:

- 9 years, 3 months ago, [Apache Zookeeper: distribution of nodes across data centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221651/apache-zookeeper-distribution-of-nodes-across-data-centers)
- 1 year, 4 months ago, [Tomcat, hide javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword from -D options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763477/tomcat-hide-javax-net-ssl-keystorepassword-from-d-options)
- 2 years, 3 months ago, [Python: pysftp exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232360/python-pysftp-exception-handling)
- 3 years, 1 month ago, [Azure POST login.microsoftonline.com/oauty2/token fails on AADSTS900144](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914875/azure-post-login-microsoftonline-com-oauty2-token-fails-on-aadsts900144)
- 3 years, 5 months ago, [If exist with multiple wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104569/if-exist-with-multiple-wildcards)
- 2 years, 8 months ago, [Cannot install miniconda on Mint Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918396/cannot-install-miniconda-on-mint-linux)

---

In order to better understand, does anybody have any ideas what is going on?  I know the standard answers for the -2 and the review bans, but all this for questions from years ago?  And all at the same time?  Did I - unknowingly - commit a *faux pas* and am being retaliated against?

Comment: Reviewing and receiving votes are completely different things; I'm not sure of your point in regards to what the votes on your content have to do with your reviews. As for why you got a review ban; presumably you have failed an audit or a it's been noticed that your decisions don't align with the community and so you have been given a suspension from the review queue again.

Comment: Your review banned is from you choosing incorrect actions during an audit or a moderator determining your review actions were incorrect when they themselves reviewed the queue item

Comment: I understand that, the question is more why now after 3-4 years, and all within 3 days.  I never got a -2 on a question in 9 years, to get 6 at the same time + review ban at the same time is - lets say- curious.

Comment: Both of those reviews you've linked have a problem of using inline code markdown for things that aren't code. `Don't use inline code markdown for something that isn't code.` If you see inline code markdown being used incorrectly, either reject the edit (if that's the only changes) or perhaps improve it to undo those changes while keeping the good changes. There was no reason for that excessive use of bold in that second review either; I honestly don't see why you approved that revision, as there's no improvement.

Comment: Q1 has more problems than just "spaces": 1. "gives" is not code but has been marked as such. 2. The code fence is only opened but never closed. 3. The extra spaces are also an issue. In Python spaces are very significant, so extras can lead to different semantics.

Comment: serial votes are normally automatically corrected. Wait a day and see of the script kicks in ...

Comment: Q2 is introducing way too much markup. For things that really don't need it. Markup should be used *sparringly* for emphasises. When **too** much **words** are **bolded**, then **there** is **nothing** is **emphasised**. It also looks ugly as hell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The age of the question is irrelevant; it's when you did the reviews that count and the second one was only 5 days ago. It looks like a moderator spotted your mistake 2 days ago and banned you. You've only just realised you're banned which is exactly why bans can't be too short. Otherwise, they time out before the person banned notices they've been banned at all.

As to why you're banned, it's because you're approving edits that add code markup to things that aren't code.

The voting was 4 votes today and 2 votes 2 days ago, so not quite all at the same time. With today's votes you just need to wait 24 hours to see if they are reversed.

Comment: I've escalated the votes manually as well. The two batches were related to each other (though not to the review suspension, to be clear)

Comment: The voting has now been corrected, thanks to an unusually fast CM

Comment: Indeed, the correction was just applied!